# Wordpress website was cloned to new domain, but redirects to old domain

Tags: wordpress, redirect, migration, clone

I cloned my website `refa.lt` on new domain infozinios(lt) but when I am trying to reach my new wp-admin I am redirected to an old domain `refa.lt`.

What I already did:

1. Cleared my browser history, cache etc.
2. Changed sitename and siteurl through phpmyadmin in wp_options
3. Added this code to wp-config.php

   ```
   define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://infozinios.lt');
   define('WP_HOME', 'http://infozinios.lt');
   ```
4. Turned off W3 Total Super Cache plugin.

I don't know what can I try to do more...

Comment: Did you replace the all the page url to new domain? Its working fine https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaRhc.png

Comment: I have check http://infozinios.lt/ url its working. No re-direction there.

Comment: Check this https://prnt.sc/memwir, https://prnt.sc/memwe8

Comment: Access the database and search for the old URL and replace it everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Simply run this script using phpMyAdmin or using SSH in your database to replace all old link to new,

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content=(REPLACE (post_content, ''refa.lt, infozinios.lt''));
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value =(REPLACE (post_content, ''refa.lt, infozinios.lt''));
```

[How to Configure a WordPress Website After its Migration](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-configure-a-wordpress-website-after-its-migration/)

[How to Migrate a WordPress Website from One Host to Another](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-migrate-a-wordpress-website-from-one-host-to-another/)

Comment: I am getting

Error
SQL query:


UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content=(REPLACE (post_content, ''refa.lt, infozinios.lt''))
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'refa.lt, infozinios.lt''))' at line 1

Comment: just check this article directly https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-configure-a-wordpress-website-after-its-migration/ ,  maybe code syntax was changed :)